# Dual sound cards in Mac OS X?

Tags: audio-recording, ableton-live

I have a Lexicon Omega studio but I need 2 additional inputs. I have read about creating aggregate core audio interface, but does anyone have experience of this in mac?

I have now found a cheap mbox 2 mini that I figure might do the trick. I need to record on the lexicons four channels and the two channels of the mbox, while listening to the sum of it via either of the sound cards. I use Ableton Live, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use 2 audio interfaces in Mac OS X, even without creating an aggregate device, but Ableton only supports one input and one output device at a time, so you'll need an aggregate device for that software.

Creating an aggregate device is easy:

- open the application "Audio MIDI Setup"
- in the audio devices window click on the "+" in the lower left corner and select "create aggregate device"
- check the boxes next to the inputs and outputs you want to use in the aggregate device

In Ableton you would then select "Aggregate Device" as your audio interface.